# Show that $f(y)=0$ for every $y \in Y$.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

> If $Y$ is a subspace of a vector space $X$ and $f$ is a linear functional on $X$ such that $f(Y)$ is not the whole scalar field of $X$, show that $f(y)=0$ for all $y \in Y$.

Suppose to the contrary, that there exists some $y_0 \in Y$ such that $f(y_0) = \alpha \neq 0$. Now notice that for any scalar $\beta$ is the underlying scalar field of $X$, we have that $$\beta = \frac{\beta}{\alpha}f(y_0) = f(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}y_0).$$ I am having trouble forming or seeing the contradiction though? Can someone please help point it out to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nearly finished. It is sufficient to observe that $ y:=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}y_0$ is in $Y$, since $Y$ is a vector space and $ y_0\in Y$. In that way you have a contradiction: $f(Y)$ would be the whole field $F$, i.e.
$$
\forall \beta\in F\quad \exists y\in Y: f(y)=\beta
$$

Answer (score 3):

You wrote "for **ANY** scalar $\beta$".

That means NO MATTER WHICH scalar $\beta$ is, the conclusion holds.

The conclusion is $\beta=f\text{ of something}$.

Thus EVERY scalar is $f$ of something.

Thus $f(Y)$ is the whole scalar field.

This contradicts the assumption that $f(Y)$ is *not* the whole scalar field.

Comment: Oh yes of course!! I can't believe I missed that.. Thank you so much :). This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $f$ is linear, s

$$\text{dim}(\text{ker}(f))+\text{rg}(f)=\dim Y.$$

Because $\text{im}(f)$ is not the whole scalar field, and $\text{im}(f)$ is a vector space (because $f$ is linear) and the scalar field has dimension $1$ :

$$\text{rg}(f)=0.$$

So $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(f))=\dim Y$, and because $\ker(f)\subset Y$, you get

$$\ker(f)=Y$$.

This is exactly $$\forall y \in Y \quad f(y)=0.$$